# How to setSurfaceTextureListener in Android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use a TextureView in Android to display preview from a camera. But, I am facing problem during setting a surface texture listener to the TextureView.
In Java, I used to do this:

```java
myTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

            }
        });
```

I have seen some posts which do this by implementing the `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener()`. But, I want to use an anonymous class as I have shown above for Java. Is it possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin you should use directly the property instead of the setter method and define the anonymous class with object keyword, like this:

```
myTextureView.surfaceTextureListener =
        object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(
                p0: SurfaceTexture?,
                p1: Int,
                p2: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(p0: SurfaceTexture?) {
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(p0: SurfaceTexture?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(
                p0: SurfaceTexture?,
                p1: Int,
                p2: Int
            ) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android studio has a function to automatically convert Java code to Kotlin.
You can use it by copying Java code and then just pasting it into a Kotlin file.
(Android studio then asks you if you want to convert it, and then you just need to press yes.)

Doing that with your code gives the following:

```
myTextureView.surfaceTextureListener = object : SurfaceTextureListener {
            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {}
            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {}
            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {}
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just started using Kotlin for Android development and I didn't know about such a great feature of Android Studio.